# vbscript Remote Consult WMI with remote account user

Tags: vbscript, wmi, remote-server, account

I have one script that consult remotely Windows Services using WMI . But in remote server the service is running with computer account and my query receive error this is my query:

```
("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE StartName = '.\NVTXL'",,48)
```

How to consult for example "Server1\NVTXL' when NVTXL is a computer account. Anybode know it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I found error.

Ajust my query to:

```
("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE StartName = '.\\NVTXL'",,48)
```

And works fine. I found in microsoft page escape character is '\' and work.

Thank you.